# Two Diffrent application not installing in single device

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I created two  different application but when when i am installing both application in single device one is replacing other

Comment: Check the packge name and version.

Comment: Go to build.gradle and check if the aplicationId is the same

Comment: thanks Tomaz Mazej it worked for me..... application id was the same

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if the application IDs are the same for both apps - they must be different. Check the `applicationId` property in the `build.gradle` files of both apps.

Answer (score 0):

**please check package name of both application**

*The package name should not be identical*

Answer (score 0):

Its because your **`applicationID` is same** in both application.

Check your `applicationId` inside your app's `build.gradle` file. and make them unique in both of your application.

Comment: thanks Bhoomika Patel it worked for me..... My application id was the same

Comment: @AVIRALSINGH glad that this helps you. Please accept this answer, so it will be helpful to others too in future.